# Good FAQ For Recompiling apps with GCC for AmigaOS?

Tags: gcc

There are a couple of open source apps I am trying to recompile to work under amigaOS.  Can someone point me to a good step-by-step guide explaining what changes (from a rule-of-thumb standpoint) I need to make to the source before it'll compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good place to [start](http://www.monkeyhouse.eclipse.co.uk/amiga/dev.htm).  [This](http://amiga.sourceforge.net/amigadevhelp/) also looks like an excellent resource.

What kind of software are you looking to port, exactly?